# How do I view and edit local storage used by WebExtensions based Firefox addon?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

So I am developing a WebExtensions based add-on for Firefox.  My add-on successfully stores and later retrieves some cruft (using `browser.storage.local.set()/get()`.  But how can I view and edit the contents interactively (using keyboard and mouse), and not using WebExtension code?  For example, to quickly modify some stored object properties and/or values by hand, for quick testing?

I figured I'd try, "Storage Inspector", SHIFT-F9 or Menu -> Web Developer -> Storage Inspector.  But there's nothing there.  I have one tab open which is on about:addons page, and Storage Inspector just has "about:addons" in each section (Cache Storage, Cookies, Indexed DB, Local Storage [I want this] and Session Storage).  But they seem tied to the about:addons page, tied to whatever tab the Storage Inspector was opened from.

Hmm, so I click on my Options page, which I configure to open in a tab, and every storage area has moz-extension://random-uuid-etc, which is not the ID of my Addon, presumably because I started the browser session with the web-ext which injects the addon into a profile, for live updates on file changes.

I know, you're saying, but, that will create a new profile each time, so you won't have any old values saved anyways.  Sure, ok, that might be an excuse if I hadn't already set stuff with the add-on before trying to find a way to view and edit.  So really that's not an excuse for the local storage to be totally blank in storage inspector.

But additionally, I am using web-ext with `-p C:\path\to\profile --keep-profile-changes`, which stores profile changes in a persistent manner.  I have verified that values previously saved from the add-on remain in local storage, even after commenting out the call to `set`, exiting, saving file, restarting, etc.

So how do I view and edit local storage used by a WebExtension based Firefox addon?

A "Web Developer" tool that has a caveat of not working for web development, is a prized dunsel in any toolkit.

Answer (score 6):

Currently this isn't possible in Firefox. Vote for https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1292234 to make it happen one day.

In the mean time, I use Chrome for Firefox WebExtensions development where the [Storage Area Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb) extension offers the feature you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

In FF 60esr I can view extension local storage data in the page rendered by navigating to `about:debugging` and selecting `debug` on the extension in question. The URL is of the form `moz-extension://{Extension UUID}/_generated_background_page.html` and it is possible to navigate directly to it. As you would expect, local storage data appears in Web Developer/Storage Inspector - example below.

As for editing it, The GUI needs some improvement, but this is possible by double-clicking in either a key or value field, as per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector#Local_storage_Session_storage).

[image]